# How to update the Grub list on the Guix OS?

Tags: grub, guix, guixsd

I installed the Guix OS in a partition of my HDD for testing, alongside my daily OS partition. Now the previous grub is overwritten and my daily distro is not accessible anymore.

I didn't found "grub-mkconfig" in the packages search. How do you update grub list with Guix please ?

Comment: Who overwrote GRUB?

Answer (score 0):

After installing GuixSD it will install its own grub. To add others OS you need to edit the configuration file `/etc/config.scm`. Here is an example:

```
 (bootloader (bootloader-configuration
            (bootloader grub-bootloader)
            (target "/dev/sda")
            (menu-entry
                (label "Debian GNU/Linux")
                (linux "/boot/vmlinuz-5.10-amd64")
                (linux-arguments '("root=/dev/sda3"))
                (initrd "/boot/initrd.img-5.10-amd64"))))))
```

Then run `guix system reconfigure /etc/config.scm`

Some example here: [10.1 Using the Configuration System](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Using-the-Configuration-System.html)

[10.13 Bootloader Configuration](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Bootloader-Configuration.html)